# A basic question about convergence of matrix

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am confused with this very basic question.

We know that for a square matrix A the following two properties are equivalent to A being a convergent matrix:

1: $lim_k\rightarrow \infty \|A^{k}\| = 0$, for all natural norms.

2: $\rho (A) < 1$

I am proving a theorem where I came across  $lim_k\rightarrow \infty \|A^{2^k -2}\|$ . My question is may I claim that   $lim_k\rightarrow \infty \|A^{2^k -2}\| = 0$, If I have additional condition that $\rho (A) < 1$ and $2^k > 2 $. $\rho (A)$ stands for the spectral radious of the matrix $A$.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is $\rho(A)$? The condition number?

Comment: @Silencer I have edited my question. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have a sequence $(u_k)$ which is convergent to $\ell$ then every subsequence $(u_{\varphi(k)})$ is convergent to the same limit.

Apply this result and take $\varphi(k)=2^k-2$ then the sequence $(||A^{2^k-2}||)$ is convergent to $0$ since $(||A^k||)$ is convergent to $0$ if $\rho(A)<1$.

Comment: Ben Thank you very much sir for your timely help.

Comment: You're welcome.